# docker - skip load tar of preloaded image

Tags: docker

My build system produces an image as exported tar file.
My tests have runtime dependency on in and they perform `docker load` on it.

I'm trying to optimize the process so I will skip the load operation if the image was already loaded (preferably based on the tar file shasum digest).

Is there any way to avoid re-loading image that was already loaded?

Comment: Set up a registry.  Don’t use `docker save` and `docker load` unless you _really_ have to, like there’s actually no network connectivity between your build system and your target system.

Comment: Unfortunately - that's exactly my case... Running in bazel. So each test execution gets a fresh sandboxed runtime environment.